# Is it possible to create Salesreceipt without product/service value through QBO API?

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Is it possible to create `Salesreceipt` without product/service value through `QBO` API? I have tried  through API but it's not reflecting rate value and storing description value only.

If I remove `ItemRef` attribute(in request body) then it's reflecting rate and amount values and  it's assigning some default and random product/service.

It is possible directly in QBO UI.

[image: Can create Salesreceipt without product/service in QBO direct UI]

**Request body where only description value storing:**

```
{
  "TxnDate" : "2016-05-27", 
  "Line" : [ {    
   "Amount" : 2222.00,
    "Description" : "hi chk",
   "DetailType" : "ItemReceiptLineDetail",
    "ItemReceiptLineDetail" : {
      "ItemRef" : { },
      "Qty" : 1,
      "UnitPrice" : 2222
    }       }
      ],
  "CustomerRef" : {
    "value" : "67"
  },
  "CustomerMemo" : {
    "value" : "Thanks for your business!  We appreciate referrals!"
  },
  "TotalAmt": 2222.00,
  "PrivateNote" : "",
  "CustomField" : [ {
    "DefinitionId" : "1",
    "Type" : "StringType",
    "StringValue" : ""
  } ]

}
```

**Request body where default product/service assigning:**

```
{
  "TxnDate" : "2016-05-27", 
  "Line" : [ {    
   "Amount" : 2222.00,
    "Description" : "hi chk",
   "DetailType" : "ItemReceiptLineDetail",
    "ItemReceiptLineDetail" : {
      "Qty" : 1,
      "UnitPrice" : 2222
    }       }
      ],
  "CustomerRef" : {
    "value" : "67"
  },
  "CustomerMemo" : {
    "value" : "Thanks for your business!  We appreciate referrals!"
  },
  "TotalAmt": 2222.00,
  "PrivateNote" : "",
  "CustomField" : [ {
    "DefinitionId" : "1",
    "Type" : "StringType",
    "StringValue" : ""
  } ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

QuickBooks Online does not support this.

Comment: Hi Keith.
Do you mean it's not possible through API?
As it's working by QBO UI, why it's not possible though API.That's my main doubt.
Do you think we can get this feature if we raise a case to QBO?



Thanks.

Comment: It is not possible to do this via the API. You can raise a support ticket with Intuit by logging into your developer.intuit.com account.

Comment: Okay.
Thank you.
We are doing some update in QBO UI like making the product value as empty  (after creating SalesReceipt and some default product is assigned). 
Do you think this kind of operation does not work through API?

Like create salesreceipt with default product and then make the  product value as empty by means of an update.